# JSONObject in JSONObject

Tags: java, android, json

I have an API Output like this:

```
{"user" : {"status" : {"stat1" : "54", "stats2" : "87"}}}
```

I create a simple `JSONObject` from this API with:

```
JSONObject json = getJSONfromURL(URL);
```

After this I can read the data for User like this:

```
String user = json.getString("user");
```

But how do I get the Data for `stat1` and `stat2`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`JSONObject`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html) provides accessors for a number of different data types, including nested `JSONObjects` and `JSONArrays`, using [`JSONObject.getJSONObject(String)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONObject%28java.lang.String%29), [`JSONObject.getJSONArray(String)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html#getJSONArray%28java.lang.String%29).

Given your JSON, you'd need to do something like this:

```
JSONObject json = getJSONfromURL(URL);
JSONObject user = json.getJSONObject("user");
JSONObject status = user.getJSONObject("status");
int stat1 = status.getInt("stat1");
```

Note the lack of error handling here: for instance the code assumes the existence of the nested members - you should check for `null` - and there's no Exception handling.

Comment: Did you mean `JSONObject user = json.getJSONObject("user")`?

Answer (score 2):

```
JSONObject mJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject userJObject = mJsonObject.getJSONObject("user");
JSONObject statusJObject = userJObject.getJSONObject("status");
String stat1 = statusJObject.getInt("stat1");
String stats2 = statusJObject.getInt("stats2");
```

from your response **user** and **status** is Object so for that use **getJSONObject** and **stat1** and **stats2** is **status** object key so for that use **getInt()** method for getting integer value and use **getString()** method for getting String value.

Answer (score 1):

To access properties in an JSON you can parse the object using JSON.parse and then acceess the required property like:

```
var star1 = user.stat1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Gson Library...

Google Gson is a simple Java-based library to serialize Java objects to JSON and vice versa. It is an open-source library developed by Google.

```
// Here I'm getting a status object inside a user object. Because We need two fields in user object itself.
JsonObject statusObject= tireJsonObject.getAsJsonObject("user").getAsJsonObject("status");
// Just checking whether status Object has stat1 or not And Also Handling NullPointerException.
String stat1= statusObject.has("stat1") && !statusObject.get("stat1").isJsonNull() ? statusObject.get("stat1").getAsString(): "";
// 
String stat2= statusObject.has("stat2") && !statusObject.get("stat2").isJsonNull() ? statusObject.get("stat2").getAsString(): "";
```

If You have any doubts , Please let me know in comments ...