# Get JSON object bundled with its key

Tags: java, json

I'm writting a parser in java for some JSON objects. I have to extract a JSON object with a `key = "some_key"` from its `parent`, another JSON object. The contents of `parent` are:

```
{"some_key":{"some contents": true}, "other_child":{..}}
```

I extract it with:

```
child = parent.getJSONObject(key));
```

And `child`'s contents are:

```
{"some contents": true}
```

And then I need to send it to another method that needs that object to be contained in one with the same key, but with no other elements (e.g. no "other_child"), so I do:

```
newObject = new JSONObject().put(key, child);
```

The contents of `newObject` are:

```
{"some_key":{"some contents": true}}
```

It works, but it doesn't seem to be the most efficient approach. Is there a more elegant way to get the same `newObject` result without having to create two objects?

I know I can do it in one line as follows, but internally is the same behavior.

```
newObject = new JSONObject().put(key, parent.getJSONObject(key));
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am following this correctly, you can create the new child json object from the parent json object itself

```
 JSONObject child = parent.getJSONObject("status");
// child.setKey...does that help?
```

You can then use this child json object for both the scenarios mentioned above.

There is a similar post [JSONObject in JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781075/jsonobject-in-jsonobject)

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: Thank you, but the idea is to get the `JSONObject` that matches the key, but contained in an object that has the same key without having to do it in two steps.

Comment: i made an edit...not sure if this goes all the way?..set the key on the child object you get?