# How to parse a JSON map in Java or Kotlin where the map has a key

Tags: java, json, dictionary, parsing, kotlin

I'm sending a Map from a server to a Android app as a JSON file. Previously I was sending Arrays, Strings, Booleans, and Longs which were decoded by null checks and

```
json.getJSONArray(key)
```

or similar, where json is a JSONObject and key is a String.

`.getJSONMap(key)` does not exist and other similar questions do not provide answers that include the case where the JSON has other data and needs a key to specify where the map is.

What can I use to parse the JSON to a map given a key?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSONObject in JSONObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11781075/jsonobject-in-jsonobject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `json.getJSONObject(key)`